# Fetch list of running activities in Android (from Lollipop devices onwards)

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I am working on a personal project where I need to fetch a list of all running packages in android. 
I have been able to fetch  a list of running applications in pre-lollipop devices using this code.

```
 ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
        List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfoList =  m.getRunningTasks(10);
        Iterator<RunningTaskInfo> itr = runningTaskInfoList.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = (RunningTaskInfo)itr.next();
            int id = runningTaskInfo.id;
            CharSequence desc= runningTaskInfo.description;
            String topActivity = runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getShortClassName();
            int numOfActivities = runningTaskInfo.numActivities;
        }
```

But it doesn't work with Lollipop devices. Can someone please assist me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the javadoc for [getRunningTasks()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29).  Basically, you can't do this any more because it's seen as a security problem for the end user.